Issue with NTAG213 Password Removal - Card Becomes Unusable After AUTH0 Modification
I'm developing a Flutter app using the flutter_nfc_kit package to manage NTAG213 NFC cards. While I successfully implemented password protection, I'm facing a critical issue when attempting to remove it. Specifically:
Problem:
Setting the AUTH0 page to 0xFF or 0x0F results in the card becoming permanently unusable (dead).
Setting the AUTH0 page to 0x00 does not disable password protection.
The card stops responding after modification, making it unusable for further operations.
Here is the code snippet for removing password protection:
Future<bool> removePasswordProtection({
  required List<int> password,
}) async {
  try {
    setStatus('Checking NFC availability...');
    var availability = await FlutterNfcKit.nfcAvailability;
    if (availability != NFCAvailability.available) {
      setStatus('NFC not available');
      return false;
    }

    setStatus('Scanning for NFC tag...');
    setScanning(true);

    var tag = await FlutterNfcKit.poll(
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10), androidCheckNDEF: true);

    setStatus('Checking if card is NTAG213...');
    if (!await isNTAG213(tag)) {
      setStatus('Not an NTAG213 card');
      return false;
    }

    setStatus('Attempting authentication...');
    var authCommand = Uint8List.fromList([
      0x1B, // PWD_AUTH command
      password[0],
      password[1],
      password[2],
      password[3]
    ]);

    try {
      var authResponse = await FlutterNfcKit.transceive(authCommand);
      print('Auth Response: ${authResponse.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(' ')}');
      if (authResponse.length < 2) {
        setStatus('Authentication failed: Invalid response');
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setStatus('Authentication Error: $e');
      return false;
    }

    // Clear password (page 0x2B)
    await FlutterNfcKit.transceive(
        Uint8List.fromList([0xA2, 0x2B, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF]));
    // Clear PACK (page 0x2C)
    await FlutterNfcKit.transceive(
        Uint8List.fromList([0xA2, 0x2C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]));
    // Modify AUTH0 (page 0x29)
    await FlutterNfcKit.transceive(
        Uint8List.fromList([0xA2, 0x29, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]));

    setStatus('Password protection reset successfully');
    await FlutterNfcKit.finish();
    setScanning(false);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    setStatus('Error: $e');
    await FlutterNfcKit.finish();
    setScanning(false);
    return false;
  }
}


What I’ve Tried:
Validating that the card is NTAG213 using the capability container check at page 3.
Clearing the password (page 0x2B) and PACK (page 0x2C) with valid values.
Writing different values to AUTH0 to disable protection, but encountering the issues described above.
